# Update DataGridView with DataAdapter

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, dataadapter

I can't get the changes from my DataGridView to work.
I was getting a concurrency error until I added a update command, error has stopped but the changes are not shown in the database.
I think I am missing something obvious but have spent the last week trying to figure it out any help would be appreciated

Using Visual Studio 2015
Windows Form with MySQL database

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form2
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim da As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim myCommandBuilder As MySqlCommandBuilder
    Private command As MySqlCommand = Nothing

    Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim serverString As String = "server = localhost; user id = root;  database=tickedoff"
        Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(serverString)
        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If

        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
        Dim insertCom As String
        Dim updateCom As String
        insertCom = "SELECT * FROM Pet"
        updateCom = "UPDATE `tickedoff`.`pet` SET petName = petName, species = species,
            breed = breed, DOB = DOB, gender = gender, weight = weight, customerID = customerID WHERE `pet`.`petID` =petID ;"

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = insertCom
        cmd.Connection = con
        Dim uCmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
        uCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        uCmd.CommandText = updateCom
        uCmd.Connection = con
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.UpdateCommand = uCmd
        dt = New DataTable

        da.Fill(dt)
        da.Fill(dt)
        With DataGridView1
            .AutoGenerateColumns = True
            .DataSource = dt
        End With
        cmd.Dispose()
        cmd = Nothing
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
        Try
            DataGridView1.EndEdit()
            da.Update(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does DataGridView1 successfully reflect the data in your database after you set datasource = dt?

Comment: You declare a command builder but dont use it - given a SELECT command it will create the other SQL for you.  add `Dim rows = da.Update(dt)` so you can see if is adding anything

Comment: DataGridView1 is showing the correct data

Comment: Probably a worthless answer, but try commenting out DataGridView1.EndEdit() and see if you have any better luck. I've always only ever needed to properly set dt as the datasource then da.Update(dt), and  it looks like you've already got that.